# Mixing dialogue and action in the same paragraph?

Tags: style, formatting, dialogue

I know you can add dialogue to the same paragraph as an action to show who's talking, but what happens when a character is making a speech and it's broken up by actions (hand movements, looking at other characters, etc)?

- Do I start a new paragraph for each action he does, even though he just continues talking?
- Do I start a new paragraph when he resumes talking?

For example, if I have two paragraphs of text, and between them is a sentence of an action, where precisely do I use paragraph breaks?

If I get rid of all the paragraph breaks, it just turns into a wall of text, but without them, I'm worried it will look needlessly broken up and chaotic.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could interrupt the dialogue with dashes wherever the action is performed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a judgement call. You can certainly combine dialogue and actions in the same paragraph, and it's generally a good idea to do so when writing about someone giving a speech. But as you said, the "wall of text" is also a potential problem.

The speech your character is giving will probably have separate ideas in it, times when you would make a paragraph break if you were transcribing the speech. That's likely a good place to make the break in your action/dialogue.

For example:

> The family was all staring at me, all waiting for me to start making
>   sense. I did my best. "I know it's been a long time. I know it's been
>   hard to figure out what I've been up to, and I'm sorry if that's been
>   frustrating."
>
> I took a deep breath. It was hard to argue with an introduction that
>   general, but I was about to get into the meat of it all, and that's
>   where the trouble would come. "The thing is, I've been doing some
>   digging. Some research, and what I've found has changed my mind about
>   so much. First of all," I said, fixing my gaze on Charlie, "I found
>   out about that night. The night you and Alexandra made the deal."
>
> Alexandra and Charlie exchanged shocked looks and Charlie started to
>   sputter out a denial, but I held up my hand and, miraculously, he
>   complied with my request for silence. I guess I must have really
>   caught him by surprise.
>
> "And I know about everything you did after that, all the ways the deal
>   played out..." etc.

Might not make sense without the context, but I think it shows the general idea? Mixing dialogue and actions in the same paragraph is good, but it's also good to avoid walls of text by using logical paragraph breaks.